# How to add border to XWPFTableCell

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, xwpf

I need a border to my XWPFTableCell like below table.

```
        **XXX Technologies**
```

__________________ 
|Name |Gender |Salary | 
__________________ 
Raji   FeMale 24000 
Ravi   Male   06790

Comment: Did you see this? http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.com/2011/12/set-background-color-and-add-border-to.html

Answer (score 6):

```
CTTc ctTc = cell.getCTTc(); 
// here is need to change... 
CTTcPr tcPr = ctTc.addNewTcPr();
CTTcBorders border = tcPr.addNewTcBorders();
border.addNewRight().setVal(STBorder.SINGLE);
```

Comment: you can use this code : (just need to add addNewTcPr())

Answer (score 3):

**This method will allow you to set the borders of table to your desired color as well.**

```
private static void setTableBorderColor(XWPFTable table, String color) {

  table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getBottom().setColor(color);
  table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getTop().setColor(color);
  table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getLeft().setColor(color);
  table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getRight().setColor(color);
  table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getInsideH().setColor(color);
  table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getInsideV().setColor(color);

  table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getRight().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(4));
  table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getTop().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(4));
  table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getLeft().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(4));
  table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getBottom().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(4));
  table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getInsideH().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(4));
  table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getInsideV().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(4));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add border to your cell like below

```
CTTc ctTc = cell.getCTTc();
CTTcPr tcPr = ctTc.getTcPr();
CTTcBorders border = tcPr.addNewTcBorders();

border.addNewBottom().setVal(STBorder.SINGLE);
border.addNewRight().setVal(STBorder.SINGLE);
border.addNewLeft().setVal(STBorder.SINGLE);
border.addNewTop().setVal(STBorder.SINGLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this helper function to style entire table (adapted from Rahul khanvani):

```
    public static void tableSetBorders(
        XWPFTable table,
        STBorder.Enum borderType,
        int size,
        int space,
        String hexColor) {

    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getBottom().setColor(hexColor);
    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getTop().setColor(hexColor);
    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getLeft().setColor(hexColor);
    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getRight().setColor(hexColor);
    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getInsideH().setColor(hexColor);
    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getInsideV().setColor(hexColor);

    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getRight().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(size));
    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getTop().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(size));
    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getLeft().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(size));
    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getBottom().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(size));
    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getInsideH().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(size));
    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getInsideV().setSz(BigInteger.valueOf(size));

    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getBottom().setVal(borderType);
    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getTop().setVal(borderType);
    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getLeft().setVal(borderType);
    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getRight().setVal(borderType);
    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getInsideH().setVal(borderType);
    table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getInsideV().setVal(borderType);
}
```